# App Fabric Error in Workflow Manager Configuration Wizard

Tags: workflow, error, sharepoint-server, configuration-wizard, workflow-manager

I have installed the Workflow Manager 1.0 on my Dev PC. and when I do a recommended configuration on the server. I get the following error Message:

[image]

Here is the Error Log:

[image]

**Note:** I have used the same account that I am logged in as the  service account during configuration.

Anything that I should check for??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add the correct accounts to appfabric group (add app pool accounts to that group)

> Log in to the front end server and select Start then right click on
>   Computer and select Manage (or Start > Administrative Tools > Server
>   Manager).
>
> Expand the options then expand Configuration then expand Local Users
>   and Groups.
>
> First, find the WindowsFabricAdministrators group and make sure that
>   the SharePoint Farm account is a member – if it is not, add it.
>
> Next, for each of the application pool accounts, make sure they are
>   members of the following groups:
>
> •IIS_USRS •WSS_WPG •WindowsFabricAllowedUsers

http://sharepoint-blog.com/appfabric-event-id-1000-and-event-id-1026-with-sharepoint-2013/

**EDIT**

Just realised what your trying todo!

no you cannot access workflow managment site from browser! its command line only and hence why your getting 403 response!

> providing a customizable monitoring solution, and providing a rich
>   management toolset, all of which can be directly accessed through the
>   IIS management console or scripted using the AppFabric modules for
>   Windows PowerShell.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677312(v=azure.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677312%28v=azure.10%29.aspx)

for monitoring

> AppFabric Hosting Services and Hosting Administration enable you to
>   perform health monitoring and troubleshooting of running WCF and WF
>   services, and to control those services. You do so in the AppFabric
>   Dashboard page of the IIS Manager

and

> Windows PowerShell cmdlets for AppFabric that you can use to perform
>   management tasks on applications and services. You can do so
>   interactively in the Windows PowerShell console, or script management
>   tasks with cmdlets. These cmdlets provide the functionality behind
>   much of the AppFabric application management UI.
>
> To open the AppFabric management tools UI, click Start, All Programs,
>   and then Windows Server AppFabric.
>
> You can also use the Windows Server Manager to work with AppFabric.
>   Open the Server Manager by clicking Start, Administrative Tools, and
>   then Server Manager. "Windows Server AppFabric" is listed under the
>   Application Server node under Roles. You can right-click the Windows
>   Server AppFabric entry to display commands for opening IIS Manager
>   with AppFabric extensions or the Windows PowerShell cmdlets for
>   AppFabric. In the center pane, you can also find links to online
>   resources and administrator tips.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677301(v=azure.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677301%28v=azure.10%29.aspx)

Comment: I added the AppPool User as you mentioned. Whom should I be logged in as when I am doing the configuratioin?

Comment: Because right now I dont get that Error message but after I finish the configuration (without any errors of course) I cant open the Worflow Admin Site (http / https). I get a message saying its forbidden.

Comment: just ammended my answer! when logged in you should be part of the server admin group!

Comment: I did all of that and ALhamdulillah its working fine. Because I was able to see the 'Workflow is connected' message in the Central Admin site. However When I create a Workflow in VS 2012. I cant see it in the list I associated and deployed. Please Help!

Comment: follow the answer here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/dffd0595-40d8-4982-ab82-ca26d2e79b2d/fetch-values-from-list-in-workflow-for-sharepoint-2013-for-vs-2012?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: Thanks for the link @ali-Sharepoint But I added the LookUpSPListItem activity yet I cant see the Workflow associated with the list.

Comment: My bad... I had not added the workflow to the feature... Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Create AD Groups Domain Scope:

- WindowsFabricAdministrators
- WindowsFabricAllowedUsers